# recurrence with exponentials

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation, master-theorem

I am trying to figure out on how to approach the problem on finding proving the asymptotic of an exponential recurrence. It is described as such:

t(n)=4t(n/2)+2^n

with t(1)=1 for n>=5

From what I know, the recurrence should lay in Θ(2^n).

My own attempts:

Usually I would approach this problem via master-theorem case 3, but from the condition that it wouldn't be able to fullfill it via Ԑ>0, with log2(4)=2 meaning, f(n) in Ω(n^2+Ԑ), could be only Ԑ=0 since 2^n in Ω(n^2). So I know pretty much, I can't use master theorem to figure out the problem.

But not sure how else to approach it. I considered using the expansion approach:

t(n)=t(n)=4t(n/2)+2^n

=4(4t(n/4)+2^(n/2))+2^n

4(4((4t(n/8)+2^n/4)+2^(n/2))+2^n

... after several reccurence I assume this comes pattern (4(t(n/2^k)+square_root(2)^(n) comes out, but I believe that is wrong. Even with knowing the pattern by using expansion, I am not sure how it would point that it lays in Θ(2^n).

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, for sufficiently large $n$:

$$t(n) \ge 2^n$$

To show that $t(n)$ is $\Theta(2^n)$, all we need to show is there exists some constant $c$ such that for sufficiently large $n$:

$$t(n) \le c\,2^n$$

If we want to do this by induction on $n$, consider what you'd need to prove the inductive step. Suppose $t(n/2) \le c\,2^{\frac{n}{2}}$. Then:

$$t(n) \le c\,2^{\frac{n}{2}} + 2^n$$

So we'd like to find a $c$ such that $c\,2^{\frac{n}{2}} + 2^n \le c\,2^n$, that is:

$$c \ge \frac{2^n}{2^n - 2^{\frac{n}{2}}}$$

As $n \rightarrow \infty$, the right-hand side approaches $1$, so pick any such $c>1$ that makes your base case correct, and the proof should be straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can substitute

$$n = \log{(m)} \tag{1}$$

Then

$$2^n = 2^{\log{(m)}} = m \tag{2}$$

Our original problem becomes

$$t(n)  =  4t(\underbrace{n/2}_{ \log{(m)} / 2\\=\log{(m)}-\log{(2)}\\=\log{(m)}-1 })  +  2^n \tag{3}$$
$$t(\log{(m)}) = 4 t(\log{(m)}-1)+m \tag{4}$$

At this point, we can substitute $n$ back in place of $\log{(m)}$:

$$t(n) = 4 t(n-1)+m \tag{5}$$

Since $t(1) = 1$, we have

$$t(2) = 4t(1) + m = m+4 \tag{6}$$
$$t(3) = 4t(2) + m = 4(m+4) + m = 4m + m + 16 \tag{7}$$
$$t(4) = 4t(3) + m = 4(4m + m + 16) + m = 4^2m + 4m + m + 64 \tag{8}$$

You can probably see a pattern at this point.  Consider that we have

$$t(n) = \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n-2}{4^k m} \right) + 4^{n-1} \tag{9}$$
$$t(n) = \left( \frac{1-4^{n-1}}{1-4}m \right) + 4^{n-1} \tag{10}$$

Finally, substituting $m = 2^n$ from $(2)$

$$t(n) = \left( \frac{1-4^{n-1}}{1-4}2^n \right) + 4^{n-1} \tag{11}$$

Alternatively, we know that

$$\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n-2}{4^k m} \right) \in O(4^{n-2}) \tag{12}$$

So, combining $(9)$ and $(12)$, we have

$$t(n) = O(4^{n-2}) + 4^{n-1} \tag{13}$$

and can conclude that $t(n) \in O(4^{n-1})$.